# (Linux) Firefox browser: audio not working but my system audio works properly

Tags: linux, firefox, audio, pulseaudio

Firefox Browser did not produce any audio output after the new update Mozilla Firefox 96.0.3. I tried clearing the cache, running Firefox in trouble-shoot mode. I came up with a solution which I have shared below.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 3):

The problem could lie in pulseaudio as mentioned [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1252773). I ran `rm ~/.config/pulse/*` and rebooting the system solved the issue.

Comment: that worked for me too, thanks for posting it here :)

Comment: worked for me as well, thanks!